# An unprecedented error with placing the Yii2 application vhost

Tags: apache, yii2, vhosts

I have encountered so far an unprecedented problem when creating a vhost for the Yii2 application. In principle, I do as usual, but the application does not want to start and shows the error NET :: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID which is not understandable at the moment. I am asking you for help because I have no idea what I can do wrong.

I am using Windows 7, Apache / 2.4.25, PHP 7

Below is the configuration of http-vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *: 80>
    ServerName aio.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/aio/panel/web"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/aio/panel/web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </ Directory>


    ErrorLog "C:/xampp/htdocs/aio/panel/runtime/logs/server_error.log"
    CustomLog "C:/xampp/htdocs/aio/panel/runtime/logs/server_access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Below are the host definitions:

```
127.0.0.1 aio.localhost
```

Here I put a photo with the folder structure:

[image]

And here its error from browser:

[image]

Have any of you encountered this problem by trying to put the application in Yii2?

And now it work fine. Sorry for the question.

Comment: you should add an answer to what fixed the problem rather than updating the question so others having the same problem might also benefit from what you followed.

Answer (score 0):

Okey I found a problem in panel/web/.htaccess. I remove lines:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```